# Google App Engine: 405 Method GET is not allowed for this resource

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm stuck at a point to implement the upload function in my web application using GAE. After submitting at /signup page, it redirects to /upload_file page, while it prompts the error 405 Method Get not allowed, and I was expecting to see the upload form.

(Got some Reference from: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/blobstore/main.py)

Appreciate any help!

Part of the code in a main python script:

```
class FileUploadFormHandler(BaseHandler): 
# BaseHandler is a subclass of webapp2.RequestHandler.
    def get(self):
        # create an upload URL for the form that the user will fill out
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_file')

        self.render('upload-file.html', upload_url = upload_url)

class FileUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):

        upload = self.get_uploads('file')[0]  ## 'file' is a var in the upload-file.html
        blob_key = upload.key()
        blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key) # instantiate a BlobReader for a given BlobStore value.
        locations = parsefile(blob_reader)
        img_url = generate_url(locations=locations)
        self.redirect('/view_map/%s' % img_url)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Home),
                           ('/signup', Register),
                           ('/login', Login),
                           ('/logout', Logout),
                           ('/upload_file', FileUploadHandler),
                           ('/view_map/([^/]+)?', ViewMap)
                           ],
                          debug=True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> After submitting at /signup page, it redirects to /upload_file page, while it prompts the error 405 Method Get not allowed, and I was expecting to see the upload form.

I think herein lies the problem. After sign up you're redirecting to `/upload_file` page which is mapped to `FileUploadHandler`, as follows: `('/upload_file', FileUploadHandler),`. Now note that `FileUploadHandler` has no **get method** to handle your redirect.

What I reckon you wanted to achieve is to render your `upload_file` template(which contains your upload form) after signup and you already have the logic setup in `class FileUploadFormHandler`. So you should instead map the `/upload_file` route to `FileUploadFormHandler`

Also you will need a route to handle the call to your `FileUploadHandler` when creating the upload url for the form the user will fill.

such as:

```
class FileUploadFormHandler(BaseHandler): 

    def get(self):
        # upload_url handles the POST call to FileUploadHandler
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.render('upload-file.html', upload_url = upload_url)
```

...

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/upload', FileUploadHandler),
     ('/upload_file', FileUploadFormHandler),
    ], debug=True)
```

---

*NOTE: You should probably come up with less confusing url paths ;)*

Comment: Thanks for you quick and helpful suggestion! Does the bolbstore example code work? Otherwise, it should be updated. :)

Comment: Which example might you be referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/blobstore/main.py

Comment: Haven't run it yet, but I believe the info there is correct and up to date plus it does what it's meant to do. I think you just seem to have confused yourself a little bit about the logic of **your** program

Comment: Now, after submitting file, a new issue that "405 POST Method is not allowed". It's quite confusing, because in the FileUploadHandler(), the post() method is supposed to get the uploaded file directly, (similar to the reference example).

Comment: Did you make this change, `upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')`? See comment in edit